# Убрать линию с графика highcgarts в R, добавленную через plotlines

Tags: r, highcharts

Использую Highcharts и Shiny. Добавляю на ось х линию через параметр `plotlines`. Необходимо её убрать, но не понимаю как это сделать.

Для JS есть функция `RemovePlotLine("id")`. Можно ли ее использовать в R и как?

Пример кода:

```
 usg_first <- read.table(file= "USG - 1k.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";")
 usg_fifth <- read.table(file= "USG - 5k.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";")

 if(!require(shiny)) install.packages("shiny")
 if(!require(highcharter)) install.packages("highcharter")
 if(!require(dplyr)) install.packages("dplyr")
 if(!require(tidyr)) install.packages("tidyr")

library(shiny)
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) 

Av_usg <- c( mean(usg_first$Average_thickness_nm), 
mean(usg_fifth$Average_thickness_nm))

Sigm <- c(sd(usg_first$Average_thickness_nm)/sqrt(length(usg_first$Average_thickness_nm)),sd(usg_fifth$Average_thickness_nm)/sqrt(length(usg_fifth$Average_thickness_nm)))

LCL <- c((Av_usg[1] - 3 * Sigm[1]), (Av_usg[2] - 3 * Sigm[2]))
UCL <- c((Av_usg[1] + 3 * Sigm[1]), (Av_usg[2] + 3 * Sigm[2]))

i <- 1

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Статистическое управление процессом"),

   sidebarLayout(
```

Вот тут задаю выпадающий список, при переключении которого должны линии обновляться.

```
  # Лист с графиками

  selectInput("mat", 
              label = "Пластина",
              choices = c("USG - 1k" = "first", 
                          "USG - 5k" = "fifth")),
      ),


        mainPanel(
      highchartOutput2("hcontainer2", height = "800px")
)

   )
)


 # Создание сервера

 server = function(input, output) {



# Настройка параметров графика


  output$hcontainer2 <- renderHighchart({
hc <- highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(data = usg_first$Average_thickness_nm,  
                type = input$plot_type,
                name = "Средняя толщина пластины, [нм]") %>%
```

Хочу удалить вот эту линию на оси Y:

```
  hc_yAxis(title =  list(text ="Средняя толщина пластины, [нм]"),
           allowDecimals = TRUE,
           plotLines = list(list(
             value = Av_usg[1],
             color = 'green',
             id = 'avg',
             width = 3,
             label = list(text = "Cреднее значение толщин",
                          style = list(color = 'black', fontWeight = 'bold'))
           ))) %>%
  hc_xAxis(visible = FALSE) %>%


if (input$mat != "first") {
  material <- switch(input$mat,
                     first = usg_first,
                     fifth = usg_fifth
  )

  if (input$mat == "first"){i = 1} else {i = 2} 

  hc <- hc %>%

  hc_rm_series("Средняя толщина пластины, [нм]")%>%
```

Вот здесь нужно вставить, что удаляю линию на оси Y.

```
  hc$y$hc_opts$yAxis$plotLines[1]<- NULL   
  hc_add_series(data = material$Average_thickness_nm,  
                type = input$plot_type,
                name = "Средняя толщина пластины, [нм]",
                ShowInLegend = FALSE) 
}


# Вывод графика
hc   })


 }  

# Запуск

 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Приведите минимальный пример кода, воспроизводящий проблему, чтобы люди которые попытаются вам помочь смогли воспроизвести проблему у себя. Приведённые вами отрывки лишь затрудняют понимание сути вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Объект `highchart` наследуется от класса `list`, поэтому доступ и изменение его структуры аналогично работе со списком. Вот пример удаления вертикальной линии с оси X. В примере ниже объект `highchart` сохранён в переменную `p`.

```
p$x$hc_opts$xAxis$plotLines[1] <- NULL # Для оси X
p$x$hc_opts$yAxis$plotLines[1] <- NULL # Для оси Y
```

Для анализа изменений, которые происходят при добавлении линий на оси, воспользуемся примером из другого ответа.

```
library(highcharter)

data(diamonds, mpg, package = "ggplot2")

hc <- hchart(mpg, "scatter", hcaes(x = displ, y = hwy, group = class)) %>% 
    hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "Month in x Axis"),
             opposite = TRUE,
             plotLines = list(
                 list(label = list(text = "This is a plotLine"),
                      color = "#FF0000",
                      width = 2,
                      value = 2),
                 list(label = list(text = "This is a plotLine"),
                      color = "#FF0000",
                      width = 2,
                      value = 6))) %>% 
    hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Temperature in y Axis"),
             opposite = TRUE,
             minorTickInterval = "auto",
             minorGridLineDashStyle = "LongDashDotDot",
             showFirstLabel = FALSE,
             showLastLabel = FALSE,
             plotLines = list(
                 list(label = list(text = "This is a plotBand"),
                      color = "#FF0000",
                      width = 2,
                      value = 30)))
```

Теперь рассмотрим куда добавляются линии:

```
str(hc$x$hc_opts$xAxis$plotLines)
#> List of 2
#>  $ :List of 4
#>   ..$ label:List of 1
#>   .. ..$ text: chr "This is a plotLine"
#>   ..$ color: chr "#FF0000"
#>   ..$ width: num 2
#>   ..$ value: num 2
#>  $ :List of 4
#>   ..$ label:List of 1
#>   .. ..$ text: chr "This is a plotLine"
#>   ..$ color: chr "#FF0000"
#>   ..$ width: num 2
#>   ..$ value: num 6
str(hc$x$hc_opts$yAxis$plotLines)
#> List of 1
#>  $ :List of 4
#>   ..$ label:List of 1
#>   .. ..$ text: chr "This is a plotBand"
#>   ..$ color: chr "#FF0000"
#>   ..$ width: num 2
#>   ..$ value: num 30
```

Для удаления линий нужно удалить нужный элемент из этих списков как показано выше в ответе.

Comment: Спасибо большое! А что значит p$x$ вначале?

Comment: Я сохранил объект `highchart` в переменную `p`. Дальше путь в структуре объекта.

Comment: К  сожалению, не получается убрать линию, вроде использую как надо, но все равно не выходит. Прикрепил пример кода в вопрос

Comment: Для оси Y путь будет `hc$y$hc_opts$xAxis$plotLines`. В вопросе не увидел кода, который удаляет линию.

Comment: Добавил код, которым удаляю. Пишет, что не может найти функцию "%>%<-". Раньше писал, что типо неправильная размерность : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: У вас на предыдущей строке пайп остался (`%>%`): это ломает код. Просмотрите свой код ещё раз внимательно. Код приведённый в ответе работает и должен использоваться отдельной командой (не в пайпах).

Comment: Посмотрите ещё раз правильный путь для оси Y: `hc$x$hc_opts$yAxis$plotLines`.

Comment: Большое спасибо, всё получилось!!!

Comment: Если ответ на вопрос найден, поставьте отметку, чтобы другим пользователям было удобнее ориентироваться в ответах.